# How did Gammon solve the puzzle in episode 2?

Tags: phi-brain

While I was watching Phi-Brain Episode 2, I tried solving the puzzles on my own. But on that sliding block game, I couldn't figure out how Gammon solved that puzzle **without moving the red car until the path was cleared**. Here's how it looks like:
[image]

The black car on the farthest left and the white car near the exit are 3 blocks long which can be confirmed from this picture below.
[image]

So when you plot it out, the puzzle would look like this: 
[image]

I'm kinda wondering how and I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I'm assuming that the red car has to be moved through the exit, and that the cars can only move forward/backward?

Comment: Yes. Same rules with the popular mobile game Unblock Me.

Comment: It seems to be solvable, but my solution isn't complete yet, and I'm willing to bet that I have some unnecessary steps

Comment: Update: no success. Being a bored, mathy person, I'm now trying to come up with a possible proof showing that it's not solvable, but I can't say I'm have much success with that either, and I rather not do something by brute-force.

Comment: it is explained in the episode, he cheated I think, by using cars to push other cars, which you aren't supposed to do. I'll try formulate an answer when I get to the train :p

Comment: For what it's worth, this prompted me to ask a question at [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1257238/126378), where it's been suggested that the puzzle can be solved. Unfortunately, I'm really too tired right now to make a fresh attempt of it.

Comment: Update: yeah, someone included a solution when answering my question, even though the focus of my question was something else.

Comment: @Maroon Read the replies, but didn't really understand the solution though.

Comment: @PeterRaeves: I'll probably try solving again and see if I get something.

Comment: @Ezui I tried to find a solution, but I had to move the red car twice before the path was cleared. Was it mentioned in the episode that the red car shouldn't move?

Comment: @PeterRaeves Well he did find a solution without moving it first.

Comment: @Ezui I'm quite sure that he moved it up and down offscreen and that in the last move it was at the back again (same as in my solution btw). You have to move it up once to move past the lower right horizontal car (car number 10) to the left. Then the red car is moved back down until the end of the game. It is impossible to solve otherwise.

Comment: @PeterRaeves From what I remember, he just moved the other cars until he was able to clear the path. I guess I'll have to rewatch it then.

Comment: @Ezui At [18:34](https://youtu.be/gwwcs1KG8JE?t=18m34s), he moves it [up for the first time](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vo7tX.png)

Comment: @PeterRaeves Right. I must've missed that part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up writing a descriptive model for it in [IDP](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/software/idp), letting the solvability prover from our univeristy prove whether a solution can be found. The fastest solution it could come up with was one finishing the game in **48 steps** (see below). Therefore the problem is indeed solvable. My first answer though, saying Gammon cheated, was indeed incorrect. It was only **after** he had solved the puzzle, that the system was sabotaged and made Kaito *cheat* to save their lives.

I numbered the cars from top to bottom and left to right as in the following picture.

[image]

The solution is written in the form `Move(t,cid,d)` with `t` being the step number in the solution, `cid` being the car identifier and `d` being the distance the car travels during that time step. `d` is positive when driving up or to the right and `d` is negative when driving down or to the left.

```
Move = {
    1,9,1; 2,4,2; 3,2,1; 4,1,-1; 5,6,-3;
    6,7,1; 7,9,1; 8,3,3; 9,7,-2; 10,6,1;
    11,1,1; 12,2,-1; 13,5,3; 14,2,1; 15,1,-1;
    16,6,-1; 17,7,2; 18,8,2; 19,10,-4; 20,8,-2;
    21,7,-1; 22,6,1; 23,1,1; 24,2,-1; 25,5,-3;
    26,2,2; 27,1,-1; 28,6,-1; 29,7,1; 30,3,-3;
    31,7,-1; 32,6,1; 33,1,1; 34,2,-2; 35,4,-2;
    36,9,-4; 37,4,2; 38,2,1; 39,1,-1; 40,6,-1;
    41,7,1; 42,3,3; 43,7,-1; 44,6,3; 45,1,1;
    46,2,-1; 47,5,4;
}
```

Comment: But Gammon did not knew this at first. He played by the rules. He only knew that it was possible after Kaito, with the help of the Armband of Orpheus, realized the trick behind the game.

Comment: And if Gammon knew, he wouldn't have been kicking the doors of the car just to escape.

Comment: @ezui yeah i rewatched the scene and there was indeed a solution without cheating. Ill change the answer when I have it calculated. My model has some error somewhere

Comment: Am I missing something. It can be solved by only 6 moves. [2:down, 4: left, 4: down, 3:down, 3: left, 5: up]

Comment: @Furkan The blocks represent cars, as you can see in the screenshot of OP's question, and cars can not move sideways (yet?). Therefore car number 2 cannot move downwards as you suggested.